# Booting from DVD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, dvd

I was using Windows 7. I thought to partition my computer and install another OS like Ubuntu. So I purchased Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic, 64 Bit DVD from Amazon.

While trying to boot from it, I was not able to properly install the DVD, mainly due to long time required and frequent power cuts. I tried to install many times, but it took long time. I used "Something else" option while installing. The Windows OS was not recognized by the Ubuntu. I tried to partition and install.

Current report of GParted is `/dev/sda/parted` into (1) `/dev/sda1` > ntfs > size 512 MiB > used 312 MiB (2) `/dev/sda2` > `lvm 2 pv ubuntu-vg` > size 931.01 GiB > used 931 GiB.

I made back ups on CD and since I have only one CD/DVD drive, using Ubuntu DVD doesn't allow me to use another CD/DVD. Before proceeding ahead with installation. I wanted to take your guidance. Also my works have been interrupted.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite Windows? The 512 MiB partition is probably the hidden boot partition but is there any regular Windows partition to keep?

Answer (score 1):

If there is any way for you to get reliable power for the install, that would be the first step.  Your Windows partition looks terribly small for Windows 7.  If you tried to manually resize, and the power died during that process, Windows may have been corrupted.  What you can do is look online for "boot repair disk" which is a small live linux that will boot from CD/DVD and try to repair the boot (both Windows and Linux) if it can.  If that does not work, then you will have to restore or reinstall Windows if you still want it.  Personally, I have always installed linux over Windows 7 and the only adjustment I made was the partition size.  Never any trouble, although as you say, it does take some time.  Again, get reliable power if at all possible.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BS6QXVm3qP/

Comment: Till date the problem is not solved. Today I tried to install Ubuntu, I waited for long time, and when the computer hanged, I had no option than to restart it. How long it will take me to install the OS in my computer? Power supply is not in my hand.

Comment: I don't see an obvious solution, sorry. If it were me, as a diagnostic, I would try to install 16.04 LTS 32-bit (that is, an old one) to see if that worked.  Ubuntu should complain if your computer does not have enough memory or a 64-bit processor, but I would try installing from the old DVD, anyway.

Comment: Dear Roderick, thanks for your support. Installing after booting from Live DVD is difficult. I am thinking to try install DVD option at boot time. But I need to be little active while starting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing Ubuntu using a USB drive instead. DVDs can be slow and clunky.

[Guide to installing Ubuntu from USB stick](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)

However, if you are trying to recover your data first... Instead of Installing Ubuntu, boot from the USB installer and have a look if your old files and partitions are still there.

Try running gparted if the drives don't appear in the Ubuntu file manager. If you're at all unsure about partitioning then you should probably ask someone who is familiar with Linux or drive partitions to help you in person. There is a real danger of corrupting or losing data if you partition drives wrongly.

The main lesson you should take from this is, always back your work up regularly, and especially before making changes to your operating system. Hopefully you're able to rescue your data and get Ubuntu working though. This is all part of the learning process of experimenting with alternative operating systems and getting to know how your computer works.